# Default browser is Chrome but links still open in FireFox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, default-programs, default-browser

Kubuntu 21.04

I installed Chrome and saw that in Applications > Default Applications, the web browser is now Chrome - cool.

However, all links I've opened from applications (such as Slack, the desktop application), open in FireFox.